# Efficient Way to Slice Strings in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-processing

I have a dataset that has over 100 million rows that I am trying to manipulate in pandas. I am trying to slice the string in `a` based on the values in `b` and `c` as the start and end points respectively.

[image]

I can do this with list comprehension like so:

```
df['d'] = [a[1]['a'][a[1]['b']:a[1]['c']] for a in df.iterrows()]
```

This is really slow. I can do the same thing with an apply like this:

```
df['d'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['a'][x['b']:x['c']],axis=1)
```

This is also quite slow. My question is, what is the most efficient way to slice the strings in `a` using the values in `b` and `c` as the start and end for the slice?

Comment: A bit stumped on this one. You might be able to go down the route of groupby with the start and end indices, and work on each group, but many of the `str` methods in pandas as really slow, so I'm not sure it will be better than `apply`. Did you try something like this?

Comment: what's the condition ?

Comment: @user3280146 ? They just need to slice the strings with the given indices. I'd say the question is pretty clear.

Comment: It says based in the value of b and c. Does it means that from column "a", the slicing should be one of the values either from column b and c. Sample output would be more easier to understand...

Comment: You said it is slow. What is the time taken for 1 million rows? I am trying to understand how slow is "slow". It will help us ballpark speed and compare any solution posted, as people mostly cannot access 100 million rows of data.

Comment: @user3280146 `df['d'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['a'][x['b']:x['c']],axis=1)`. `b` is the start index and `c` is the end index of the slices

Comment: @roganjosh I did not try any groupby yet. Honestly, I'm not very good with groupbys.

Comment: @CypherX I just ran tests on 10,000,000 rows. I should have just done 1,000,000. It took 15 mins for the list comprehension and 3.5 minutes for the apply.

Comment: Thank you Kyle. @a_guest's solution is by far the best, when I tested as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating over `df.iterrows()` is really slow because for each row it creates a separate `pd.Series` object. For 100 million rows this means 100 million such objects are being created (and discarded). It's better to `zip` the columns and use this in a comprehension like so:

```
df.assign(d=[a[b:c] for a, b, c in zip(df['a'], df['b'], df['c'])])
```

This will only create three `Series` objects and then iterate over them which saves a lot of overhead.

You can also take a look at [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#str) to write your own function that loops over the data frame.

Comment: Umm...wow! This takes my process down to 4 seconds. I tried so many different things and was nowhere near that speed.